# Decode audio file chunks using decodeAudioData() in Firefox

Tags: firefox, audio, mime-types, web-audio-api

I converted the audio file to aac-adts and send it to client as chunks.
then append all chunks to a buffer to be played.
the problem in Firefox that it throws "The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type." error only with the second chunk.

After checking the mimetype of the first chunk "audio/x-hx-aac-adts" and the second chunk "application/octet-stream". it seams to be different.

Firefox decodes the first chunk successfully, but not the other.

any help??

```
request.open("GET", "/Content/AudioFiles/chunk-2.aac", true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.send();
request.onload = function () {
    var undecodedAudio = request.response;
    context.decodeAudioData(undecodedAudio, function (data) {
        sourceBuffer.buffer = data;
        numberOfChannels = sourceBuffer.buffer.numberOfChannels;
        var splitter = context.createChannelSplitter(numberOfChannels);
        var channels = document.getElementById('channels');
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfChannels; i++) {
            var element = '<div class="channelDiv"><input type="checkbox" class="channel" onclick="toggleChannel(' + i + ')" id="channel' + i + '"/> <label for="channel' + i + '">channel ' + i + '</label></div>';
            channels.innerHTML += element;

            $('.channel').each(function (index, item) {
                item.checked = true;
            });
            gains[i] = context.createGain();
        }

        sourceBuffer.connect(splitter, 0, 0);

        //Connect splitter' outputs to each Gain Nodes
        gains.forEach(function (item, index) {
            splitter.connect(item, index);
            item.connect(context.destination, 0);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you be sure the second chunk also begins at an ADTS header? AAC is a strip of (audio) frames each with header. PS: Can you show the **first 9 bytes** of your AAC? (Save the file and use a free **hex editor** tool to see file's bytes). From that you can calculate frame size as bytes length allowing clean chunks (multiple frames) that can each play like a separate file... PS: Are you using **constant** bitrate (CBR), or **variable** bitrate (VBR)?

Comment: PS: Fist two bytes should begin as `FF F1` so what does remaining 5 bytes look like? That is the ADTS header (repeated every frame, and needed to decode each frame).

Comment: I think what is happening is that I split the file in the middle of the frame not at the beginning. so there is no header data. when I remove the rest on the frame data and make the chunk starts with the next frame. it works.

Comment: so, How can I split the file according to the frames to make every chunk starts with a frame? @VC.One

Comment: I need to know your AAC bytes to advise. Open your AAC file in a hex editor (or use this [**online viewer**](https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/)). The beginning first byte should be `FF` and second byte is `F1`... after that what are the following 7 bytes? Also important, is your AAC encoded as constant bitrate or variable bitrate? Since that can affect header offsets...

Comment: thanks alot @VC.One. it works now!